# When should I restart webrick and when should I not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

I'm currently learning developing ruby on rails applications.

If i make changes in the views should i need to restart webrick ? What about controllers, models ?

When exactly should i restart webrick during development of a rails app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views and Controllers, changes in public folder -- Don't Restart

Model -- Sometimes restart, sometimes not

Everything Else -- Researt

When you are confused and things don't work -- Restart

Answer (score 3):

The rule of the thumb is  You don't restart when you code but you restart when you configure.

For instance, changes in views -> code -> no restart

changes in models -> code -> no restart

But:

changes in anything under config/ directory (environments, routes, ...) -> configuration -> restart

Added a new gem to Gemfile -> bundle install -> configuration ->  restart

Comment: In development routes are reloaded on each request (at least for me). Changes to database schema (under db/) require server restart.

Comment: modifying routes.rb does not require a restart

Comment: true, I was wrong. Then the logic can be that routes should be considered part of your developing workflow and thus dont require restart.

Answer (score 3):

Restart when:

- you modify the database (e.g., `rake db:migrate`)
- you modify configuration files
- you add gems

Other than that, you can pretty safely leave webrick running for all other changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed in views and that is not reflecting on your web browser though you have refresh the page. This happens because it is stored in cache memory. At this time you no need to restart the WEBrick. Just clear the cache memory.
And it is recommended that whenever you made any changes to gemfile you should restart the WEBrick.